# Delphi: overlap window/form titlebar?

Tags: forms, delphi, window

Is it possible to overlap the form title bar with an other control (TPanel) ?

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: This is not possible if you do things the normal way. Of course, there are always "tricks" you can use to achieve something similar, but they are hard to get right. (For instance, just think about the RAD Studio IDE: The title bar controls get severely displaced when you maximize the window by dragging it to the top of the screen using the mouse!) The easiest thing to do is to skip the title bar altogether and add your own buttons in the upper right corner. You can use Windows hit testing (`WM_NCHITTEST`) to make the simulated title bar work as it should.

Comment: This is called the non-client area of the form. Technically, you're not supposed to put anything there. But of course there are features which allow it, but are getting quite technical. Especially when it comes to covering both client and non-client areas in the same control. You might be better off with a totally separate window, treated as a popup menu of sorts.

Comment: I needed something like this once before, I used another transparent form over my main form, I couldn't find a way to put a control to cover both client and non-client area.

Comment: consider it you can design your own custom titlebar and set the form's `Border Style` on `bsNone`.

Comment: I found this solution [https://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/setting-up-a-custom-titlebar/](https://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/setting-up-a-custom-titlebar/) and it works very well, except for one small thing: the code does the thin black form border to deasappear and I can't find the code section responsible for it. Does anyone know how I can get back the black border?

Comment: So, *"is it possible to overlap the form title bar with an other control"* or not?

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz Yes, it is possible, but not without effort, as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

As [Jerry comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60667679/delphi-overlap-window-form-titlebar#comment107355555_60667679), maybe you could do with a StayOnTop form on which you put your panel. Assuming you design that panel as a (possibly left aligned) control on your mainform, the beginning of such a solution could look like this:

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
  private
    FStickIt: TForm;
  protected
    procedure WMSysCommand(var Message: TWMSysCommand); message WM_SYSCOMMAND;
    procedure WMWindowPosChanged(var Message: TWMWindowPosChanged);
      message WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TMainForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FStickIt := TForm.CreateNew(Self);
  FStickIt.AutoSize := True;
  FStickIt.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  FStickIt.FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
  FStickIt.Show;
  Panel1.Align := alCustom;
  Panel1.Parent := FStickIt;
end;

procedure TMainForm.WMSysCommand(var Message: TWMSysCommand);
begin
  inherited;
  case Message.CmdType and $FFF0 of
    SC_MINIMIZE: FStickIt.Hide;
    SC_RESTORE: FStickIt.Show;
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.WMWindowPosChanged(var Message: TWMWindowPosChanged);
var
  EdgeSize: Integer;
  TitleBarInfoEx: TTitleBarInfoEx;
begin
  inherited;
  if Assigned(FStickIt) then
  begin
    EdgeSize := (Width - ClientWidth) div 2;
    FStickIt.Left := Left + EdgeSize - BorderWidth;
    FStickIt.Top := Top + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYBORDER);
    Panel1.Height := Height - EdgeSize - GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYBORDER) +
      BorderWidth;
    TitleBarInfoEx.cbSize := SizeOf(TitleBarInfoEx);
    SendMessage(Handle, WM_GETTITLEBARINFOEX, 0, LPARAM(@TitleBarInfoEx));
    Constraints.MinWidth := Panel1.Width + TitleBarInfoEx.rgrect[5].Right -
      TitleBarInfoEx.rgrect[2].Left + 2 * EdgeSize - 2 * BorderWidth;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This could be a very nice solution, but it has some unsightly effects, such as the disappearance of the overlaped form immediately before minimizing an some others. However, I am sure, that these issues could be fixed.